# How to have a border width for a splitter container bar separator in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

The splitter container bar separator by default has no width so you can just see an ugly dotted line in the GUI. How to have a width like splitter in Visual Studio ? I can't see any property for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach is to give the panels distinct BackColors so that it is obvious where to place the cursor to start dragging.  Another thing you could do is put a Panel on the left side and set its Dock property to Right.  Give it a distinct BackColor and set its width to 2.